# How can I turn down the sensitivity of my brightness slider?

Tags: shortcut-keys, brightness

**How can I make the brightness change in smaller increments?**

I red this before ([How to increase the screen brightness control sensitivity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/287509/how-to-increase-the-screen-brightness-control-sensitivity/326606#326606)), but I didn't find the solution to help in my case.

My laptop brightness is controlled by vendor specified hotkey (<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> & <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>), so there is no interface for OS (Ubuntu 12.10) to adjust brightness.

When I try to adjust, the slider moves by steps of 40% (0-40-80-100 & 100-60-20-0). **Is there a way to set the steps by 20%?**

Answer (score 0):

I did it by setting **acpi_osi=** instead of **acpi_osi="!Windows2012"**
Now it works.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this answer?