# Brightness slider is too fine (14.04)

Tags: 14.04, dell, laptop, brightness, backlight

I'm running ubuntu 14.04 on a Dell laptop (XPS 13 Developer Edition). The brightness slider stopped working (the slider would fill up and empty as usual but the brightness wouldn't change).

[This fix](http://itsfoss.com/fix-brightness-ubuntu-1310/) got it working again: this is the text I added to the conf file

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier  "card0"
    Driver      "intel"
    Option      "Backlight"  "intel_backlight"
    BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection
```

However, now the brightness changes in what I assume is 1% increments - way too fine, especially given it takes a few ms to actually change, so if you bash it repeatedly then the brightness keeps changing long after you stop.

[This answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/103249/how-to-increase-brightness-in-smaller-steps) suggests that it's hardware based, which is unlikely given the problems I'm having.

[This answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/328324/how-can-i-turn-down-the-sensitivity-of-my-brightness-slider) looks promising (I read elsewhere that Windows pseudo-supports 100 brightness levels even if the hardware actually rounds them up) but is really vague.

How can I implement the fix in the last link? Or, how can I disable the native brightness buttons and remap them to just run xbacklight commands?